# how to select an item of a dropdown using selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, dropdown

I'm trying to click on `"Universität Bern"` which is an option of a dropdown that can be found in the following [link](https://www.zssw.unibe.ch/usp/zms/login.php?):

I used the following code to get to the page (link), but I'm not able to click on an opetion of this dropdown. My code is :

```
     import content as content
     from selenium import webdriver
     from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
     import time

     path = "C:\Program Files\chromedriver.exe"
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
     driver.get("https://www.zssw.unibe.ch/usp/zms/angebot/6728/index_ger.html")
     pathanmelden = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//* 
     [@id='content']/section/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a")
     pathanmelden.click()
     time.sleep(1)
     pathforstudents = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/input")
     pathforstudents.click()
     chosetheuniversity = driver.find_element_by_class_name("")# This is what does not work"
```

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This drop down is not build using select and option tag so select class won't work.

You should first click on drop down arrow and then click on the desired element.

**Code:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.zssw.unibe.ch/usp/zms/angebot/6728/index_ger.html")
pathanmelden = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//* [@id='content']/section/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/a")
pathanmelden.click()
time.sleep(1)
pathforstudents = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[2]/div[2]/form/input")
pathforstudents.click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img#user_idp_iddicon"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@title='Universities: Universität Bern']"))).click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**PS:** I have not changed your existing locators, you can change them as well since they are absolute xpath. `time.sleep(2)` is just for visualization purposes. You can remove that once you test out the code.

Comment: "Universities" should be replaced by "Universitäten", otherwise it works properly, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following by sending your text then press Enter:

**Java Code:**

```
WebDriver driver;
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofSeconds(30, 1));
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.get("https://www.zssw.unibe.ch/usp/zms/login.php?");
By y = By.xpath("//INPUT[@id='user_idp_iddtext']");
driver.findElement(y).clear();
Thread.sleep(2);
driver.findElement(y).sendKeys("Universität Bern");
Thread.sleep(2);
driver.findElement(y).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

**Python:**

```
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

driver.get("https://www.zssw.unibe.ch/usp/zms/angebot/6728/index_ger.html")
x= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//INPUT[@id='user_idp_iddtext']")
x.clear()
time.sleep(1)
x.send_Keys("Universität Bern")
time.sleep(1)
x.send_Keys(Keys.ENTER)
```